# HotChocolate v13 GraphQL: how to get rid of "Input" suffix?

Tags: c#, graphql, webapi, hotchocolate

I'm building GraphQL API with C# and HotChocolate. The library adds "Input" suffix to type names which used as input arguments. I want to get rid of this behavior. And no, we're not going to discuss why do I want this, and why it is a good practice (even if you really want to, please don't).

Documentation: https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/input-object-types

> Note: If a class is used as an argument to a resolver and it does not end in Input, Hot Chocolate (by default) will append Input to the type name in the resulting schema.

And nothing about how to turn this default behavior off (of course).

I've tried an attribute GraphQLName:

```cs
[GraphQLName("ProductFilter")]
public record ProductFilter
{
    ...
}
```

Nope, didn't help. It utilizes GraphQLName, yes, but also adds "Input" in the end.

Next, I tried to implement my own naming convention. Pretty straightforward: treat input objects as regular objects, and the rest of types - in a default way:

```cs
public class NoInputNamingConvention : DefaultNamingConventions
{
    public override string GetTypeName(Type type, TypeKind kind)
    {
        if (kind == TypeKind.InputObject)
        {
            return base.GetTypeName(type, TypeKind.Object);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.GetTypeName(type, kind);
        }
    }
}
```

And it almost worked out, but now I have the following error:

```
The name `MailingAddress` was already registered by another type.
```

In my API MailingAddress is used as both input object and regular object (a property of some class). So, looks like the library treats them as two different types, and that's why we see the error above.

Any other ideas to try? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a type (input, scalar or output) has to be unique in a schema. Meaning you cannot have a output type and a input type with the same name. This is defined in the [GraphQL Spec Section 3.3](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Schema)

```
All types within a GraphQL schema must have unique names. No two provided types may have the same name. No provided type may have a name which conflicts with any built in types (including Scalar and Introspection types).
```